# Logics that can not be implemented in current logical frameworks like Coq?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, math-software, meta-math, metalogic

Are there logics that can not be implemented in current logical frameworks like Coq. Why those logics can not be implemented? And what should be improved in existing logical frameworks/proof assistants to allow implementation of those logics as well.

The question is about properties and types of such non-implementable logics. But specifically I am researching non-monotonic, defeasible, adaptable logics and I don't know whether should I give effort to implement them in Coq (or other prood assistant) and should I seek other logical frameworks (maybe there are small but powerful ones) or should respect those logics as two strange and implement from the scratch in some programming language.

By "implementation" I mean creating theorem prover, satisfiability checker.

Comment: This link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/areas/reasonng/defeasbl/dprolog/0.html is for D-Prolog, which might be useful. The page says "an extension of Prolog implementing defeasible reasoning". This page http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016792369090005C is an abstract for a paper that talks about a DSS implemented in d-prolog.

Comment: You can certainly represent the metatheoretical reasoning in even a relatively weak system like LF (e.g. as implemented by Elf or Twelf) let alone a rather powerful system like the Calculus of Inductive Constructions. This is probably what "implementing" actually means for you unless you want a system like Prolog or some constructive interpretation. It's quite possible you could even (non-trivially) *embed* these logics into Twelf/Coq so that you can leverage the metatheoretic machinery those implementations already have. For example, there are embeddings of linear logic into LF.